Multiple installs of flutter app on device
I have an app that works fine, however, no matter how it's installed, either from Google or via running, 3 apps are installed onto the device, all are identical and are treated as the same application.
AndroidManifest (Main) - other manifests don't make a difference and don't contain an action
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />    
    <application
        android:label="myapp"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        tools:replace="android:label"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">

        <!-- For schedules -->
        <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationReceiver" />
        <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:showWhenLocked="false">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_EXACT_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
</manifest>

build.gradle (app)
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

android {
    namespace "com.example.myapp"
    compileSdkVersion 34
    ndkVersion "26.1.10909125"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0.1'
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled = false
            shrinkResources = false
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled = false
            shrinkResources = false
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.window:window:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0'
    coreLibraryDesugaring("com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:2.0.3")
}


I've tried changing the application id

I created a new project and re-imported each package I was using individually and tested each one, there were two packages that weren't compatible or that were deprecated:

share (replaced with share_plus)
image_gallery_saver (replaced with gal)

